# How to upload logo to my fb application?

Tags: facebook, image

I have an application created in facebook, along with the integration for my existing website.    When users on my website use the facebook connect button and receive the facebook message that "WebsiteABC" will receive the following info:  your public profile, friend list and email address," I need to get my logo updated in the box within that pop up window.

I'm looking at all of the settings within the app at developers.facebook.com, but cannot find anywhere to upload that logo.  Can someone help please?

Thanks

Comment: Go to App Details and upload a Logo

Comment: When I go to App Details, the area that allows image uploads does have several logo sizes to upload but none are anywhere near the size allotted for the logo in the popup window -